# Выбор в таблице по значению из первой таблицы

Tags: delphi

Нужно в первой таблице, выбрав жанр, просто тыкнув на поле, или поиском, можно фильтрацией, должно выбить в другой таблице все названия по этому жанру, только по этому.

Comment: Привет!
Надо по точнее задать вопрос.
 1. Версия дельфи
 2. Таблицы в чем? BDE?
 3. Master-Detail что такой знаете?
Копайте в сторону Master-Detail.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я например, знаю 2 варианта: либо SQL-запрос написать на выборку, либо фильтрацией. Для запросов нужен компонент TQuery (TADOQuery) в его свойстве SQL нужно написать что-то типа того:

```
SELECT * <написать звёздочку или перечислить нужные поля> FROM <название таблицы>
WHERE <название поля, где записан жанр> = <требуемый жанр>
```

А затем запрос открыть методом Open или присвоить свойству Active значение true.
Фильтрация: у каждого набора данных (компонента таблицы или запроса) есть свойство Filter, нужно написать:

```
ADOTable1.Filter:='Имя поля с жанром = '+QuotedStr(Edit1.Text);
ADOTable1.Filtered:=True;
```

Можно сделать фильтрацию при наборе текста (жанра в Вашем случае). Подробнее можно почитать в книге Флёнова М. Е. "Библия Delphi" - там на примере телефонного справочника работа с БД показана.

Comment: Забыл о доп инфе сор,Delphi 7,database desktop